# Http Status 404 for JSF

Tags: maven, jsf

I can't open my xhtml file in anyway . I've tried solved posts but still getting 404. I've tried with glassfish , tomcat and wildfly . Getting "HTTP Status 404 – Not Found " error. Thanks in advance

index.xhtml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
```

web xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<display-name>whatfitstome</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

Pom.xml (for jsf) :

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>whatfitstome</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>whatfitstome Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JSF 2 API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0-m07</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>whatfitstome</finalName>
</build>
  </project>
```

My project structure

[image: 1].

When am try to run project result:

[image: 2]

Comment: Start by removing `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
` and check the deployment and for java-ee servers set the jsf api to provided

Comment: In case of Tomcat, your pom.xml is missing a JSF implementation. Watch out for exception stack traces in your log. In case of Glassfish/Wildfly I'd guess JSF API should be scopes `provided`.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Please remove the slash before the `index.xhtml`

i.e.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: So `<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>` like in the web.xml above is not good?

Comment: @Kukeltje Can you give a more detailed information why the `welcome-file-list` is not good. I have used it a lot of times and found this information at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnaer/index.html

Comment: There IS a welcome-file list in the web.xml in the application in the question. So it is not a matter of adding one, but it **might** be that it is wrongly configured, so please compare.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. I haven't seen it. But the slash at the beginning is wrong. I will correct my answer

Comment: The slash at the beginning works for me (Wildfly 10, Wildfly 14)

Comment: But the 'slash' doesn't work on Tomcat. From the Servlet 3.1 spec.: `The welcome file list is an 
ordered list of partial URLs with no trailing or leading /. `

Comment: Good find... then Wildfly 10-14 at least has a 'bug' since it is servlet 3.1 https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Getting+Started+Guide. But since the OP does not provide a web-app version info and uses the namespace prefixes wrong, it might even be that it is not used at all for OP (regardless of the / workging there or not).

Comment: oh and must not != may not ;-) Maybe there is the 'difference' ? Hmmm... Hope this is the solution for OP but I think not since OP also tested Wildfly. Hmmmm... So many other basic things could be wrong (even a 'app is not deployed at all' can be a reason)

Answer (score 0):

If you run your project on `TomcatEE` server, only `jsf-api` is required, but if you run the project on `Tomcat` server, you need `javaee-web-api`, `jsf-api`, `jsf-impl`, defining only `jsf-api` will cause `Http Status 404` for navigating to your `*.xhtml` files

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```